# iterating through an array to transfer its elements to a vector with certain conditions (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, partitioning, stdvector

I am a Grade 10 student taking a Computer Science course over the summer and I am having trouble with my homework question.

The question asks to write code that will allow a user to enter 6 grades and sort the grades into two different vectors; one that stores passing grades and another that stores failing grades (>=60 means you pass). In the end, it wants you to print all the passing and failing grades in their respective place (passing grades on one line, failing grades on the other).

So far, my code accepts the user's input and successfully stores it into an integer array with 6 elements. However, after accepting the input, this error shows up:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
signal: aborted (core dumped)
```

Please look at the snippet below:

```
int userGrades[6]; 
vector <int> passingGrades; 
vector <int> failingGrades; 
  
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cout << "Enter the grades of Student " << i+1 << ": "; 
    cin >> userGrades[i]; 
}

for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {

        if (userGrades[x] >= 60) {
            passingGrades.at(x) = (userGrades[x]);
            break;
        }
        else {
            failingGrades.at(x) =(userGrades[x]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int pgSize = passingGrades.size(); 
int fgSize = failingGrades.size(); 

cout << "The passing grades are: "; 
for (int a = 0; a < pgSize; a++) {
    cout << passingGrades[a] << ", "; 
}

cout << "The failing grades are: "; 
for (int b = 0; b < fgSize; b++) {
    cout << failingGrades[b] << ", "; 
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `for (int y = 0` loop?  You don't use the `y` variable in those loops.

Comment: it served no purpose, it was simply a mistake that i overlooked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vectors `passingGrades` and `failingGrades` have no elements, so any access to their "elements" are invalid.

You can use [`std::vector::push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add elements to a `std::vector`.

Also note that the loop using `y` looks meaningless because the code inside the loop doesn't use `y` and executes `break;` in the first iteration.

In conclusion, the part:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {

        if (userGrades[x] >= 60) {
            passingGrades.at(x) = (userGrades[x]);
            break; 
        }
        else { 
            failingGrades.at(x) =(userGrades[x]); 
            break; 
        } 
    }
}
```

should be:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {

    if (userGrades[x] >= 60) {
        passingGrades.push_back(userGrades[x]);
    }
    else { 
        failingGrades.push_back(userGrades[x]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot! I realized that the for loop with y was useless as well, but have no idea why I didn't remove it! Also, is there a reason we have to use push_back() instead of at()?

Comment: @tanisha -- `at()` only accesses elements, it doesn't create new ones.

Comment: @tanisha Also your fixed input array isn't needed to input those values at all. You can directly input the values got via `std::cin` into the vector.

Answer (score 1):

These nested `for` loops do not make sense:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) {

        if (userGrades[x] >= 60) {
            passingGrades.at(x) = (userGrades[x]);
            break; 
        }
        else { 
            failingGrades.at(x) =(userGrades[x]); 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

For example, the index `y` is not used. And secondly, both vectors are initially empty, so you may not use the member function `at()`. Otherwise, an exception will be thrown.

It will be enough to use a range-based `for` loop, for example:

```
for ( const auto &x : userGrades )
{
    if ( x >= 60 ) 
    {
        passingGrades.emplace_back( x );
    }
    else
    {
        failingGrades.emplace_back( x );
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 6;
    unsigned int userGrades[N] =
    {
        60, 50, 70, 40, 80, 30 
    } ;
    std::vector<int> passingGrades; 
    std::vector<int> failingGrades;     

    for ( const auto &x : userGrades )
    {
        if ( x >= 60 ) 
        {
            passingGrades.emplace_back( x );
        }
        else
        {
            failingGrades.emplace_back( x );
        }
    }

    if ( not passingGrades.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "The passing grades are: "; 
        for ( const auto &x : passingGrades )
        {
            std::cout << x << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There are no passing grades\n";
    }

    if ( not failingGrades.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "The failing grades are: "; 
        for ( const auto &x : failingGrades )
        {
            std::cout << x << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There aew no failing grades\n";
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The passing grades are: 60, 70, 80, 
The failing grades are: 50, 40, 30,
```

Or, instead of a `for` loop, you could use the standard `std::partition_copy()` algorithm. For example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::partition_copy( std::begin( userGrades ), std::end( userGrades ),
                     std::back_inserter( passingGrades ),
                     std::back_inserter( failingGrades ),
                     []( const auto &x )
                     {
                         return x >= 60;
                     } );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 6;
    unsigned int userGrades[N] =
    {
        60, 50, 70, 40, 80, 30 
    } ;
    std::vector<int> passingGrades; 
    std::vector<int> failingGrades;     

    std::partition_copy( std::begin( userGrades ), std::end( userGrades ),
                         std::back_inserter( passingGrades ),
                         std::back_inserter( failingGrades ),
                         []( const auto &x )
                         {
                             return x >= 60;
                         } );    

    if ( not passingGrades.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "The passing grades are: "; 
        for ( const auto &x : passingGrades )
        {
            std::cout << x << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There are no passing grades\n";
    }

    if ( not failingGrades.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "The failing grades are: "; 
        for ( const auto &x : failingGrades )
        {
            std::cout << x << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n'; 
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There aew no failing grades\n";
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
The passing grades are: 60, 70, 80, 
The failing grades are: 50, 40, 30,
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simpler Program**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define PASS 60
int main(){
    int pass[6], fail[6],grades[6];
    cout<<"Please key in the grades:\n";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
        cout<<"Please key in the grade "<<i<<" :";
        cin>>grades[i];
        cout<<"\n";
    }


    //Displaying pass and fail vectors
    cout<<"Passing grades: \n";
    int y;
    for(y=0;y<=6;y++)
    {

        if(grades[y]>=PASS)cout<<grades[y]<<"\n";
    }

    cout<<"Failed grades: \n";
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<=6;x++)
    {
        if(grades[x]<60)cout<<grades[x]<<"\n";
    }

return 0;
}
```